# Choose from an existing set of weights to make a target sum

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

When doing weightlifting, I want to make a specific weight by attaching several plates to a bar.

I have the following plates:

- 6 plates of 1 kg each
- 6 plates of 2.5 kg each
- 6 plates of 5 kg each
- 6 plates of 10 kg each

The bar itself weighs 10 kg.

It's only allowed to attach the plates in pairs - they are attached at each end of the bar, and the arrangement at the two ends must be completely symmetrical (e.g. attaching two 5-kg plates at one end, and one 10-kg plate at the other end is forbidden for reasons of safety).

Make a program or a function that tells me how many plates of each kind I have to use in order to get a given total weight. The input is an integer greater than 11; the output is a list/array/string of 4 numbers. If it's impossible to combine existing plates to get the target weight, output a zero/empty array, an invalid string, throw an exception or some such.

If there are several solutions, the code must output only one (don't make the user choose - he is too busy with other things).

Test cases:

```
12 -> [2 0 0 0] - 2 plates of 1 kg plus the bar of 10 kg
13 -> [0 0 0 0] - a special-case output that means "impossible"
20 -> [0 0 2 0] - 2 plates of 5 kg + bar
20 -> [0 4 0 0] - a different acceptable solution for the above
21 -> [6 2 0 0] - 6 plates of 1 kg + 2 plates of 2.5 kg + bar
28 -> [0 0 0 0] - impossible
45 -> [0 2 6 0] - a solution for a random number in range
112 -> [2 4 6 6] - a solution for a random number in range
121 -> [6 6 6 6] - maximal weight for which a solution is possible
```

If your code outputs the numbers in the opposite order (from the heavy plate to the light one), please specify this explicitly to avoid confusion.

Comment: Isn't this a dupe of the [minimum coin counting question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70847/31625)? I don't think the same greedy algorithm fails, except with the restriction of 6 of one kind of plate. I think that might not be sufficient difference, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The greedy algorithm doesn't work (not without modification, at least) exactly because the numbers are limited

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62862/42963), but that one is ASCII

Comment: Yes, the reason I posted was that I was unsure that the modification was significant enough. I posted to try to get community feedback, and I'll remove my comment if it seems like the community disagrees with me.

Comment: Can we output all solutions instead of just one?

Comment: No, you should choose one. I'll add a clarification.

Comment: Can we assume all input to be less than 122?

Comment: @busukxuan No - it must work for any number. But in certain languages (e.g. C) you can limit the range at 127, using [this guideline](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8471/25315). Also, if it fails in a different way for 28 and 122 - it's good enough, as long as it does fail.

Comment: I don't think the [linked challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8655/36398) is a duplicate. That one asks to find _all_ subsets with _any_ number of elements, and doesn't have the _symmetry_ restriction. I didn't realized my dupe-hammer worked the way around too, though. I only intented to vote to reopen and gather more opinions @PeterTaylor

Comment: @LuisMendo, the symmetry restriction is irrelevant: it just reduces to having 3 pairs of weight 2kg, 3 pairs of 5kg, etc. As for the "all subsets" difference, there are a few other questions which this is a more direct dupe of which have also been closed as a dupe of that one, and I preferred to cut out the middleman.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Feel free to mark as dupe again then. I only intended to cast a vote

Comment: @LuisMendo, each person only gets one close vote per question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
4ṗạµ×2,5,10,20S€+⁵iƓịḤ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=NOG5l-G6ocK1w5cyLDUsMTAsMjBT4oKsK-KBtWnGk-G7i-G4pA&input=MTEy) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=NOG5l-G6ocK1w5cyLDUsMTAsMjBT4oKsK-KBtWnGk-G7i-G4pArCouG5hCQ4wqHhuZvigJw&input=MTIKMTMKMjAKMjEKMjgKNDUKMTEyCjEyMQ).

#### How it works

```
4ṗạµ×2,5,10,20S€+⁵iƓịḤ  Main link. No arguments

4                       Set the left argument and initial return value to 4.
 ṗ                      Take the Cartesian power of [1, 2, 3, 4] and 4, i.e.,
                        generate all 4-tuples of integers between 1 and 4.
  ạ                     Take the absolute difference of all integers in the
                        4-tuples and the integer 4. This maps [1, 2, 3, 4] to
                        [3, 2, 1, 0] and places [0, 0, 0, 0] at index 0.
   µ                    Begin a new, monadic chain. Argument: A (list of 4-tuples)
     2,5,10,20          Yield [2, 5, 10, 20].
    ×                   Perform vectorized multiplication with each 4-tuple in A.
              S€        Sum each resulting 4-tuple.
                +⁵      Add 10 to each sum.
                   Ɠ    Read an integer from STDIN.
                  i     Find its first index in the array of sums (0 if not found).
                     Ḥ  Unhalve; yield the list A, with all integers doubled.
                    ị   Retrieve the 4-tuple at the proper index.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
4t:qEZ^!"[l2.5AX]@Y*10+G=?@.
```

For inputs that have no solution this produces an empty output (without error).

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NHQ6cUVaXiEiW2wyLjVBWF1AWSoxMCtHPT9ALg&input=MjE)

#### Explanation

```
4           % Push 4
t:q         % Duplicate 4 and transform into range [0 1 2 3]
E           % Multiply by 2: transform into [0 2 4 6]
Z^          % Cartesian power. Each row is a "combination" of the four numbers
!           % Transpose
"           % For each column
  [l2.5AX]  %   Push [1 2.5 5 10]
  @         %   Push current column
  Y*        %   Matrix multiply. Gives sum of products
  10+       %   Add 10
  G=        %   Compare with input: are they equal?
  ?         %   If so
    @       %     Push current column, to be displayed
    .       %     Break loop
            %   Implicit end
            % Implicit end
            % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 70 bytes

```
Select[FrobeniusSolve[{2,5,10,20},2#-20],AllTrue[EvenQ@#&&#<7&]][[1]]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a number as input, and either outputs a list or errors and returns `{}[[1]]` if there is no solution.

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, 25 bytes

```
×2,5,10,20S+⁵⁼³
4ṗ4’ÇÐfḢḤ
```

[Try it here.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5cyLDUsMTAsMjBTK-KBteKBvMKzCjThuZc04oCZw4fDkGbhuKLhuKQ&input=&args=MTEy&debug=on)

Comment: `2,5,10,20` -> `2,5,⁵,20`

Comment: really... isn't `,` a dyad? My whole life is a lie

Comment: @LeakyNun `,` is a dyad, but it can also be used for literals. `2,5,⁵,20` isn't a literal though (`2,5` and `20` are, but `,`, `⁵` and `,` are atoms), so you'd need something to combine the links.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 112 bytes

```
lambda n:[i for i in[[i//4**j%4*2for j in range(4)]for i in range(256)]if i[0]+2.5*i[1]+5*i[2]+10*i[3]+10==n][0]
```

An anonymous function that takes input, via argument, of the target mass and returns the number of each plate as a list. If no solution exists, an error is thrown. This is pure brute force.

**How it works**

```
lambda n                                   Anonymous function with input target mass n
...for i in range(256)                     Loop for all possible arrangement indices i
[i//4**j%4*2for j in range(4)]             Create a base-4 representation of the index i,
                                           and multiply each digit by 2 to map from
                                           (0,1,2,3) to (0,2,4,6)
[...]                                      Package all possible arrangements in a list
...for i in...                             Loop for all possible arrangements i
i...if i[0]+2.5*i[1]+5*i[2]+10*i[3]+10==n  Return i if it gives the target mass
[...]                                      Package all solutions in a list
:...[0]                                    Return the first list element. This removes any
                                           multiple solutions, and throws an error if there
                                           being no solutions results in an empty list
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/kxXC91)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 50 bytes

```
,L##l4,L:{.~e[0:3]}a:[2:5:10:20]*+:10+?,L:{:2*.}a.
```

Returns `false` when not possible.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>34</s> <s>31</s> 25 bytes

```
h+fqQ+;s*VT[1 2.5 5;)yMM^U4 4]*4]0
yMh+fqQ+;s*VT[2 5;y;)^U4 4]*4]0
yMhfqQ+;s*VT[2 5;y;)^U4 4
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=yMhfqQ%2B%3Bs%2aVT%5B2+5%3By%3B%29%5EU4+4&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=12%0A13%0A20%0A21%0A28%0A45%0A112%0A121&debug=0)

Errors in impossibility.

This is essentially a brute-force.

This is quite fast, since there are only 256 possible arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 202 bytes

Decided Scala doesn't get much love here, so I present a (probably not optimal) solution in Scala.

```
def w(i:Int){var w=Map(20->0,10->0,5->0,2->0);var x=i-10;while(x>0){
var d=false;for(a<-w.keys)if(a<=x & w(a)<6 & !d){x=x-a;w=w.updated(a,w(a)+2);d=true;}
if(!d){println(0);return;}}
println(w.values);}
```

The program outputs in reverse order and with extra junk compared to solutions in post. When a solution is not found, prints 0.

Note: I could **not** remove any of the newlines or spaces because Scala is dumb, so I think to reduce size, the method must be redone unless I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

### APL, 40 bytes

```
{2×(4⍴4)⊤⍵⍳⍨10+2×,⊃∘.+/↓1 2.5 5 10∘.×⍳4}
```

In ⎕IO←0. In English:

1. `10+2×,∘.+⌿1 2.5 5 10∘.×⍳4`: build the array of all the possible weights, by computing the 4D outer sum of the weights per weight type;
2. `⍵⍳⍨`: search the index of the given. If not found the index is 1+the tally of the array at step 1;
3. `(4⍴4)⊤`: represent the index in base 4, that is, compute the coordinate of the given weigth in the 4D space;
4. `2×`: bring the result to problem space, where the coordinates should be interpreted as half the number of the plates.

Example:
              {2×(4⍴4)⊤⍵⍳⍨10+2×,⊃∘.+/↓1 2.5 5 10∘.×⍳4}112 
    2 4 6 6

[Bonus](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B2%D7%284%u23744%29%u22A4%u2375%u2373%u236810+2%D7%2C%u2283%u2218.+/%u21931%202.5%205%2010%u2218.%D7%u23734%7D12%2013%2020%2021%2028%2045%20112%20121&run): since APL is an array language, several weights can be tested at once. In this case the result is transposed:

```
      {2×(4⍴4)⊤⍵⍳⍨10+2×,⊃∘.+/↓1 2.5 5 10∘.×⍳4}12 13 20 21 28 45 112 121
2 0 0 6 0 0 2 6
0 0 0 2 0 2 4 6
0 0 2 0 0 2 6 6
0 0 0 0 0 2 6 6
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 109 bytes

```
n=>`000${[...Array(256)].findIndex((_,i)=>i+(i&48)*9+(i&12)*79+(i&3)*639+320==n*32).toString(4)*2}`.slice(-4)
```

Returns `00-2` on error. Alternative solution that returns `undefined` on error, also 109 bytes:

```
n=>[...Array(256)].map((_,i)=>`000${i.toString(4)*2}`.slice(-4)).find(s=>+s[0]+s[1]*2.5+s[2]*5+s[3]*10+10==n)
```